# Decrementing a number in React State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to decrement my `timeLeft` property on my state by one every second. In the `startRecording` function I call the `startTimer` method but can't seem to get the state to decrease. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
class NimbusCamera extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    navigator: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }
  state = {
    camera: {
      aspect: Camera.constants.Aspect.fill,
      captureTarget: Camera.constants.CaptureTarget.disk,
      type: Camera.constants.Type.front,
      captureMode: Camera.constants.CaptureMode.video,
      captureAudio: true,
      flashMode: Camera.constants.FlashMode.auto
    },
    isRecording: false,
    timeLeft: 30,
    reachedLimit: false
  }
  startTimer = () => {
    console.log('Starting timer...')
    let timerId = setInterval(countdown, 1000); // Run function every second
    const countdown = () => {
      console.log('Counting down...')
      if (this.state.timeLeft === 0) {
        clearTimeout(timerId);
        this.setState({isRecording: false})
      } else {
        console.log(Decrementing...)
        this.setState({timeLeft: this.state.timeLeft - 1});
      }   
    }
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state)
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Camera
          ref={(cam) => {
            this.camera = cam;
          }}
          style={styles.preview}
          aspect={this.state.camera.aspect}
          type={this.state.camera.type}
          captureAudio={this.state.camera.captureAudio}
          flashMode={this.state.camera.flashMode}
          >
          <Text>{this.state.timeLeft}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.capture} onPress={this.startRecording.bind(this)}>[CAPTURE]</Text>
          <Text style={styles.capture} onPress={this.stopRecording.bind(this)}>[STOP]</Text>
        </Camera>
      </View>
    );
  }

  startRecording = () => {
    if (this.camera) {
      this.camera.capture({mode: Camera.constants.CaptureMode.video})
          .then((data) => this.props.dispatch(getPath(data.path)))
          .catch(err => console.error(err));
      this.startTimer();
      this.setState({
        isRecording: true
      });
    }
  }

  stopRecording = () => {
    if (this.camera) {
      this.camera.stopCapture();
      this.setState({
        isRecording: false
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you're calling `setInterval` on `countdown` before `countdown` is declared, I'm not sure but since that is a local function then the first statement is `let timerId=setInterval(undefined,1000);`

Comment: @niceman I tried putting it inside the countdown function but didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I didn't suggest to put it inside countdown, that would be very wrong, I suggested to put it after countdown, that is after the curly brace that ends `countdown` function

Comment: @niceman Did that. I `console.log('decrementing')` in the `else` block of the countdown function and nothing is showing up in the console so the function doesn't even seem to be getting invoked. And also putting it after would make `timerId` undefined correct?

Comment: change your countdown into an arrow function to have `this` bound to the component instead of setInterval - `const countdown = () => {...}`

Comment: @MattAft I had tried this but forgot const :/ So this got it to work once but now it's pretty inexplicably not working again? I updated my code with what I have now. You see anything? It's not getting to the else block again. Hm.

Comment: @maxwellgover so if you put a console.log at the top of your countdown function, it only runs it once? and that one time it hits the else block?

Comment: @MattAft Yeah the console.log statements in the countdown function aren't printing to the console.

Comment: does it print "Counting down..." without printing "Decrementing", by the way you forgot to wrap `Decrementing...` in quotes

Comment: by the way, where are `Camera` class and component coming from ? and `Text` component too ?!!!

Answer (score 1):

Incrementers like ++ and -- wont work. Anytime you want to update state based on a previous state value you should use this syntax.

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({ timeLeft: prevState.timeLeft - 1 });
```

Try putting your state object in a constructor:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    camera: {
      aspect: Camera.constants.Aspect.fill,
      captureTarget: Camera.constants.CaptureTarget.disk,
      type: Camera.constants.Type.front,
      captureMode: Camera.constants.CaptureMode.video,
      captureAudio: true,
      flashMode: Camera.constants.FlashMode.auto
    },
  isRecording: false,
  timeLeft: 30,
  reachedLimit: false
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for some reason. I print out the state to the screen so I can see it and it's not decrementing there or in the console.

Comment: You declared `timerId`, but you never invoked it

Comment: doesn't `setInterval` "invoke it" ? the returned ID is for stopping/canceling it

Comment: updated my answer, not sure if this is your problem but its worth a shot

Answer (score 0):

The simple way;

```
    this.setState(state => {
      return {
        timeLeft: state.timeLeft - 1,
      }
    });
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for some reason. I print out the state to the screen so I can see it and it's not decrementing there or in the console.

Comment: by the way, this should be in a code block not code snippet :)

Answer (score 0):

Because `--` executes *after* `timeLeft` in the object is assigned. It's not a reference, so the value `setState` gets is the one before decrementing.

```js
var out = document.getElementById('out');
var outCorrect = document.getElementById('outCorrect');

function setState(newState) {
  out.innerHTML = newState.timeLeft;
}

function setStateCorrect(newState) {
  outCorrect.innerHTML = newState.timeLeft;
}


var timeLeft = 10;

setState({timeLeft: timeLeft--});

var timeLeftCorrect = 10;

setStateCorrect({timeLeft: timeLeftCorrect - 1});
```

```html
<span id="out"></span>
<span id="outCorrect"></span>
```

Run the snippet and see why. `a - b` executes *before* the resulting value is assigned, `a--` is executed after.